# WPF ListBox Button Selected Item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox with some textblocks and a button -- in the button's codebehind it calls a method passing the currently selected listbox item, this works great. The issue is that when I select an item and then click the button on another item it doesn't update the "SelectedItem" property -- is there a way Xaml or C# that I can force a button click to select the parent ListBoxItem?

**Xaml**

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click" Height="30" Width="30">
            <Image Source="Resources\Image.png" />
        </Button>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataField}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: So there is a button and a textblock for each ListBoxItem? Can you post your XAML or give us a slightly better idea how this is set up?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
var curItem = ((ListBoxItem)myListBox.ContainerFromElement((Button)sender)).Content;
```

Comment: Chose as answer for simplicity.

Comment: This works for a range of sender elements! Used it for (Grid)sender.

Comment: great answer, would never have known about the ContainerFromElement function

Answer (score 4):

When a Button is clicked, it sets e.Handled to true, causing the routed event traversal to halt.

You could add a handler to the Button which raises the routed event again, or finds the visual ancestor of type ListBoxItem and sets its IsSelected property to true.

EDIT

An extension method like this:

```
public static DependencyObject FindVisualAncestor(this DependencyObject wpfObject, Predicate<DependencyObject> condition)
{
    while (wpfObject != null)
    {
        if (condition(wpfObject))
        {
            return wpfObject;
        }

        wpfObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(wpfObject);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
myButton.FindVisualAncestor((o) => o.GetType() == typeof(ListBoxItem))
```

Comment: What would a method like this look like? How would I find the visual ancestor of the ListBoxItem the button is on?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `ListBoxItem` to the command parameters.

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteItemCommand, ElementName=listBox}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

**CODE:**

```
    public ICommand DeleteItemCommand => new RelayCommand(obj => DeleteItem(obj));
 
    private void DeleteItem(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is ItemName item)
            Items.Remove(item);
    }
```