# SelectedItem of ListBox with DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, selecteditem

I have a `Listbox` with `DataTemplate`. The `DataTemplate` contains `UserControl` element. If I clicked on the `UserControl` element the Item, which contains this `UserControl` does not become the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox`. If I clicked anywhere in the area of item except it's `UserControl`, it is selected.

How can I select the item of ListBox`by clicking on the area belongs item's UserControl`?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfQuestion, Mode=TwoWay, 
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         Grid.Row="1" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
         x:Name="ListOfQuestion" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQuestion, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ListBox.Resources>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
       <DataTemplate> 
             <local:usc_QuestionEdit x:Name="QuestionList"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I posted an asnwer but it's kind of hard to get it right without code samples. Upload your code so we can help you better

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I doesn't know how to catch this event in the Item.
Code:
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfQuestion, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" 
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ListOfQuestion" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQuestion, Mode=TwoWay}">
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <local:usc_QuestionEdit  x:Name="QuestionList"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. first the `</ListBox.Resources>` doesn't seem to be in place and second the usercontrol doesn't seem to be binded to anything...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the user control is catching the mouse click and not the listbox. That is why it doesn't get selected. If you are using code-behind, you can use the events with the `Preview` prefix to catch the click higher in the control hierarchy.

To learn more about this events read about *[Routed Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* on MSDN

Update: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139996/wpf-listbox-button-selected-item) seems to have the answer you are looking for.

Hope this helps